# Efficiency of using include in showing different external pages in one <div>

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is it more efficient to use `include` in showing different external pages in one `<div>`? By more efficient, I mean in terms of speed of loading the pages and it's effectiveness compare to using `ajax` and `javascript`. Honestly, I prefer to use this as this is the simplest way and I'm not very familiar with achieving this through `javascript` or `ajax`.

I currently have this `navigation <div>` and `content <div>` codes:

```
<div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav" id="link_ul">
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#so">SO Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#po">PO Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#si">SI Reports</a></li>
      <li><a href="#comm">Comm Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div class="content">
  <div id=home class=section>
  <?php 
  include("test3.php"); 
  ?>
  </div>
  <div id=so class=section>
  <?php 
  include("test2.php"); 
  ?>
  </div>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
```

Comment: This way can be used if your web page hardly being updated. Because as you may already know in this way, you're loading every thing at once then showing/hiding content with no further loading. Slow start but fast lasting.

Answer (score -1):

I would use Ajax, because then it loads asynchronously. This way the user can already interact with the page while it loads the rest.
If you are using jQuery, this could be really simple:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#home").load("test3.php");
    $("#so").load("test2.php");
});
</script>
```